# BigQuery: Return data for one specific data source after certain date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a question and wonder if anyone can help. I'm trying to return engagements of different data sources (please see below to see how I generated values under data source on BQ), please see the screenshot as an example. For data source 1234 I need to return everything, however for data source 5678 I want the query to only return data after 5/22/22 (see "after" as the expected outputs). Is there a way to do so? Many thanks!

[image: example]

Here is how I got the data source from BQ:

```
DECLARE data_set_list ARRAY<STRING>

DEFAULT ['1234','5678'];


CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `XXX.XXX.719`  (Data_source STRING, Date DATE, device STRING);

FOR data_set IN (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(data_set_list) as id) DO

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

FORMAT(

"""

INSERT INTO `XXX.719`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this query (I ran this query in BigQuery and sampleData as sample table):

**Emulated Table:**

```
WITH sampleData AS
 (SELECT '1234' as dataSource, date('2022-05-21') as Date, 'mobile' as device UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234', date('2022-05-22'), 'desktop' UNION ALL
  SELECT '5678', date('2022-05-22'), 'mobile' UNION ALL
  SELECT '5678', date('2022-05-23'), 'mobile' )
```

**Query:**

```
select * from sampleData where dataSource = "1234"
UNION ALL
select * from sampleData where Date > date('2022-05-22') and dataSource = "5678" ;
```

With the output below:

[image]

For reference you can view query syntax for BigQuery [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax).

Comment: Hi Nestor thank you it's really helpful. I'm wondering if there's a way for me to filter the data source 5678 while during the "insert" step. Selected your answer as the best btw :)

Comment: I Appreciate it : ), I would suggest creating another question with the description mentioned above since the initial question does not include inserting query . (This is for better visibility of the question for users to answer.) Provide expected output, things that you have tried and other details that can help answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to find: per Datasource, unique device on latest date. If so, this query might help.

Sample data and codes given below. Sample data is your raw table and second block is actual code to get the desired result.

```
WITH sampleData AS
 (SELECT '1234' as DataSource, date('2022-05-21') as Date, 'mobile' as device 
   UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234', date('2022-05-22'), 'desktop' UNION ALL
  SELECT '5678', date('2022-05-22'), 'mobile' UNION ALL
  SELECT '5678', date('2022-05-23'), 'mobile' )

select * except(rank) from (
   select *, rank() over (partition by DataSource, device order by Date desc) rank 
   from sampleData)
where rank = 1
order by DataSource, Date;
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad, sorry I wasn't clear, I wasn't looking for the latest date for each data source, mainly just wanted to filter one data source while doing insert. Thanks for your query anyway because that's really good example on the usage of "partition by". Upvoted your answer!